# Como quitar las comillas de un print en Phyton de una select

Tags: python, mysql

Hola como puedo quitar las comillas de esta select:

```
    mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM jugadores")
    myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
    for x in myresult:
        print(x)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Porque por ejemplo en esta select:

```
        sqql="SELECT distinct(Nombre_equipo) FROM nba.jugadores"
        mycursor.execute(sqql)
        myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
        for x in myresult:
            print('||', end="   ".join(x))
            print()
```

Me printea esto:

```
||76ers||Bobcats||Bucks||Bulls||Cavaliers||Celtics||Clippers||Grizzlies||Hawks||Heat||Hornets||Jazz||Kings||Knicks||Lakers||Magic||Mavericks||Nets||Nuggets||Pacers||Pistons||Raptors||Rockets||Spurs||Suns||Supersonics||Timberwolves||Trail Blazers||Warriors||Wizards
```

Yo lo que quiero es que en la select (en el primer ejemplo) me la devuelva sin comillas y sin paréntesis .Gracias

Answer (score 2):

No es que el select te devuelva cosas con comillas, es que te devuelve una tupla dentro de la cual tienes elementos que son números y otros que son cadenas, y estás imprimiendo la tupla "directamente" en lugar de imprimir sus elementos.

Cuando imprimes una tupla o una lista, Python te la muestra tal como la escribirías en el código fuente, es decir, entre paréntesis (o corchetes) y con sus elementos separados por comas. Además si alguno de los elementos es una cadena, te la mostrará entre comillas, tal como la escribirías también en el fuente.

Por tanto el problema no es lo que el select te devuelve, sino lo que Python te imprime. Para que lo imprima como quieres, debes convertirlo a una cadena, para lo cual debes convertir cada uno de los elementos de la tupla en cadena (los que ya sean cadenas no pasa nada por convertirlos en cadena de nuevo, quedan igual) y después concatenarlos todos mediante un `.join()`. Puedes usar para la concatenación el carácter que quieras, por ejemplo el espacio (o una coma, o lo que prefieras).

Así pues, el código sería:

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM jugadores")
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
for x in myresult:
    separador = " "  # Aqui puedes poner si prefieres ", "
    cadena = separador.join(str(parte) for parte in x)
    print(cadena)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvió de mucha ayuda tu explicación!!